# variable always with two decimal not working?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having problem with decimals. It's a strange problem.

I have a variable that gets a value with two decimal places. But the variable does not remain with two decimal places.

code:

```
public test:number = 129.90;

ngOnInit(){

  console.log(this.test);

}
```

print this

```
129.9
```

I need this

```
129.90
```

I do not want to work with .toFixed(2), because I do not want to round.
does anyone know how to leave the variable with two decimal places?

Comment: Why? The value of the number and the format of the number as a string are two separate things.

Comment: I need two decimals because I will need to manipulate as a string. I'll use the .toString() to manipulate as a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor ( private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe ) { }

ngOnInit() { console.log(this.decimalPipe.transform(this.test, "1.2-2") }
```

or use in html:

`{{ test | number:"1.2-2" }}`

[Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)